# Getting all unique keys and their count in mongo nested documents

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a database of users and their attributes. Around 40mil+

```
{
  uuid:xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx
  ... : ....
  ... : ....

  attributes {
    age : xxxx
    gender : xxxx
    incomegroup : i
    ... : ...
    ... : ...
  }
}
```

I just don't know what are the fields in the attributes sub-document. I have no idea of it at all. For some users, the attributes document might not exist as well.

I need to know what all keys exist in attributes in the entire database and the number of users who have them like -

age : 45000 users etc.

Can i do this from a mongo query ? I need to execute something of this sort from PHP and get the counts periodically like once a day through cron job into another mysql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your current schema, you can utilize [map/reduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) to count the unique attribute fields across your collection. Consider the following example:

```
<?php

$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->test;
$c = $db->users;
$c->drop();

$fields = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; ++$i) {
    $user = ['attributes' => []];

    foreach ($fields as $pos => $field) {
        if (0 == $i % ($pos + 1)) {
            $user['attributes'][$field] = 1;
        }
    }

    $c->save($user);
}

$map = <<<'EOF'
function() {
    for (var key in this.attributes) {
        emit(key, 1);
    }
}
EOF;

$reduce = <<<'EOF'
function(k, vals) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i in vals) {
        sum += vals[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
EOF;

$result = $db->command([
    'mapreduce' => 'users',
    'map' => new MongoCode($map),
    'reduce' => new MongoCode($reduce),
    'out' => ['inline' => 1],
]);

foreach ($result['results'] as $fields) {
    printf("%s: %d\n", $fields['_id'], $fields['value']);
}

$c->drop();
```

Here, I inserted 1,000 documents into a collection, populating each with `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` attributes depending on some modulo arithmetic. They we define a map function that Mongo will use to iterate over the collection, emitting a value of `1` for each attribute key per document. The reduce function then processes these results by emission key and sums the values. Our result ends up as:

```
a: 1000
c: 334
b: 500
d: 250
```

While this is all well and good, the current schema with its dynamic field names presents a problem for indexing. For each field you intend to query on, you would have to define an explicit index for it on the collection. If instead `attributes` was an array of embedded objects (e.g. `{k: 'age', v: 25}`), you could then take advantage of [multikey indexing](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys). I highly suggest reading Derick Rethan's post on [Indexing Freeform-Tagged Data](http://derickrethans.nl/indexing-free-tags.html), which discusses this in depth.

Additionally, this schema would allow us to take advantage of the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) (available in MongoDB 2.1.0+). You're likely to find the aggregation framework easier to develop with over map/reduce. There is also a performance and concurrency benefit, since processing is not done in JavaScript. Rewriting the above example with the schema change and new aggregation in mind, we get:

```
<?php

$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->test;
$c = $db->users;
$c->drop();

$fields = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; ++$i) {
    $user = ['attributes' => []];

    foreach ($fields as $pos => $field) {
        if (0 == $i % ($pos + 1)) {
            $user['attributes'][] = ['k' => $field, 'v' => 1];
        }
    }

    $c->save($user);
}

$result = $db->command([
    'aggregate' => 'users',
    'pipeline' => [
        ['$project' => ['attributes' => 1]],
        ['$unwind' => '$attributes'],
        ['$group' => [
            '_id' => '$attributes.k',
            'count' => ['$sum' => 1],
        ]],
    ],
]);

foreach ($result['result'] as $fields) {
    printf("%s: %d\n", $fields['_id'], $fields['count']);
}

$c->drop();
```

You should find the output the same. Feel free to crank up the test size and see if you can spot a performance difference for large collections.